# config.m4 file is missing when compiling gmp php extension in lampp suite

Tags: php, php-extension, gmp, lampp, phpize

I am trying to compile the gmp for lampp suite with php 7.1.7 with api version  20160303 .
I downloaded gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2 used 
`bzip2 -dk gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2` 
to get tar file then `tar -xvvf gmp-6.1.2.tar` then `cd gmp-6.1.2/`.
When i run
 `/opt/lampp/bin/phpize` (i am using lampp suite for dev), 
I got this

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/opt/lampp/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

I am trying to compile gmp for php7.1.7.

Without running /opt/lampp/bin/phpize, and following these steps

1. ./configure
2. make
3. make test
4. make install

Its all compiling without any error with  api version  **20151012** but my php say its needs **20160303** 
Running php on console, I am getting this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20151012
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20151012
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: what's your extension source?

Comment: I have download gmp source files from https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2

Comment: this is not the PHP extension, this is the GMP library, PHP extension uses the GMP library

Comment: the PHP_SRC comes with gmp extension by default, but you still needs to enable it while you are compiling the PHP itself with the flag `--with-gmp`

Comment: I didn't compile php, check question, I am using lampp suite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your comments, in order to compile a specific version of GMP extension, you will need to clone the PHP-SRC repository, and compile the PHP GMP extension.

```
git clone git@github.com:php/php-src.git
```

you may clone a the targeted branch rather that cloning the whole repository

```
git clone -b PHP-7.1.7 git@github.com:php/php-src.git --depth 1
```

then go to the GMP extension directory & phpize the extension and complete your compilation steps.

```
cd php-src/ext/gmp
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I also want to add that if compiling extension with lampp suite, provide php-config path while using `./configure --with-php-config=PATH_PHP_CONFIG`

Comment: this answer deserves more upvotes.